# How to use Python regex pattern matching with re.findall(pattern, string)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pattern-matching, findall

I need to match to the strings "Johnson" and "Jackson", but not the string "Jason." Using Python, I need to use the function findall in the RegEx library.

I tried:

```
a = "Jackson, Johnson, Jason"
b = re.findall("J*\w{2}*son", a)
```

and it did not work! If there is anyone that can help, i would very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

findall only works with a string as input not a list.

You probably want to use `map` and `re.match` or `re.search` for example:

Also your regex has multiple repeat symbols in it and needs some tuning, this one seems to work `J\w{3}son`

```
import re
a = ["Jackson", "Johnson", "Jason"]
c = list(map(lambda x: re.search("J\w{3}son",x), a))
print([i.string for i in c if i])
```

output:

```
['Jackson', 'Johnson']
```

---

Update if your input type is just a string then your original expression was fine you just need to change the regex to the example above

```
import re
a = "Jackson Johnson Jason"
b = re.findall("J\w{3}son", a)
print(b)
```

output:

```
['Jackson', 'Johnson']
```

Comment: I wrote it wrong! So sorry, just updated it

Comment: @JamesD  use your original statement with the regex in my example: